How to extend a background not background image in tailwind
I want to be able to apply a background with a gradient. It doesn't work with the extend in config.
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'custom-gradient':
          "radial-gradient(101.05% 128.77% at -3.11% -1.41%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%), #070707 !important",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}

with the div:
<div class="bg-custom-gradient">
    </div>

It makes sense to me that it shouldn't be a background-image but a background,. Or do I just directly add the style to the div? What would be the correct route to do here?
Example below:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/U7l1EhMiCM

EDIT: It works if it's just a background:


The value you are setting for the property, is simply invalid. If I replace yours with something generic copy&pasted from the MDN, radial-gradient(circle at center, red 0, blue, green 100%) !important, it works fine. https://play.tailwindcss.com/2Vv2F4oCST?file=config

@CBroe I added an edit. It does work on other gradients. But what I wanted was to apply that particular gradient and it only works if it's a background, not a background-image.

That's because you are trying to set a gradient and a background color at the same time - radial-gradient(...), #070707 !important - the #070707 is not part of the gradient.

@CBroe, i see. so i should put it as another class. something like background-color maybe, and use it the same time as my bg-custom-gradient?

@CBroe. it worked. https://play.tailwindcss.com/1W36rTKdGI

Shouldn't need two separate classes though, you can use the same class in the extend for both backgroundImage and backgroundColor

@CBroe yes, you're right. it works with the same class name per utility name
